# ERROR! 'file' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible

new playbook test is not working. Newbie to ansible but have read throuugh the docs , samples etc.
What is wrong ?
`ERROR! 'file' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

The error appears to have been in `'/home/NTNET/mresnick/testdel.yml'`: line 10, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- file: "path=/tmp/{{ item }} state=absent recurse=no"
  ^ here


---
- name: test playbooktestdel
- hosts: temp3
  tasks:
- name: "delete old files Aveksa"
- file: path=/tmp/{{ item }} state=absent recurse=no
  with_items:
    - { Aveksa.tar }
    - { sudo_commands }
    - { baz }
...
```

Comment: Corrected copy of yml  :  ---
- name: test playbooktestdel
- hosts: temp3
  tasks:
- name: "delete old files Aveksa"
- file: path=/tmp/{{ item }} state=absent recurse=no
  with_items:
    - { Aveksa.tar }
    - { sudo_commands }
    - { baz }
...

Answer (score 30):

You wrote a tasklist and tried to run it as a playbook.

When you have a playbook, you can have a `tasks` key in a given play, and list your preferred task there.

```
---

- hosts: your hosts
  tasks:
    - name: delete sg
      file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
        state: absent
        recurse: no

...
```